# iOS - Collapsible header view inside a tableview(uiscrollview)

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiscrollview

I am trying to achieve something similar to the **parallax** effect. Wont say exactly the parallax. I have a header view that is a part of the table view.
I did set the **contentInset** of the table view to change the location of the first cell.

The amount of the top contentInset added is the height of the header view as header view is placed in blank space created by changing the content inset.

As tableview has a default scrollview along with it so in **viewDidScroll** i added the following code to hide the header view as the scrollview scrolls down.

```
    var scrollOffsetY = abs(scrollView.contentOffset.y);

        scrollOffsetY -= headerView.bounds.size.height;

        if(scrollView.contentOffset.y <= 0-self.topDistance && abs(scrollView.contentOffset.y) <= headerView.bounds.size.height ){
            print("\(scrollOffsetY)");
//
            self.headerView.transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(CGAffineTransformIdentity, 0, scrollOffsetY);

        }
        self.headerView.setNeedsLayout();
        self.headerView.layoutIfNeeded();
    }
```

Now the problem is, the as the scroll down sometimes the header view is not fully collapsed. Is there any other way or some modifications that can help to make the transition smooth.

Comment: Did you get this answered?

Comment: Please check into this.. I actually used this component to solve my problem https://github.com/bryankeller/BLKFlexibleHeightBar